# elasticsearch - time series - search time intersection between two indexes

Tags: join, elasticsearch, time-series

I have two indexes. Each one of them has time and value.
[click to see the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5amMZ.jpg)

In the example above I would like to find a specific time where Index2.val-Index1.val>70
Note that the values do not change from the last time entry which means that if a value is set to 20 on the 1-1-14 it will be the same on the 2-1-14 if no entry exists.

A solution can be fetching both of the vectors and do it with a linear algorithm but I suppose that the performance will be bad. 
Is there an out of the box solution for that?
Thanks
David

Comment: What version of ES are you using? If you're using ES 5.x I suggest investigating the `date_range` data type: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html

Comment: I'm using 5.2.2.

Comment: Let us know if the `date_range` data type does the trick for you.

Comment: I haven't found something that can be done with the range data type. I would appreciate if you give an example if you have an experience with it. Thanks